# MVC Controller handle POSTed JSON as a string

Tags: asp.net-mvc, modelbinders

I have a 3rd party app making POST submissions to my site with *application/json* in the body. I can capture a strongly typed object as:

> public string Postback([FromBody]MyResponse myResponse)

My problem is that after having gotten this much working I'm directed to support a 2nd type at the same endpoint. Therefore I need to accept a string value (instead of the result of the model binder) and then JsonConvert the string to one or the other of the 2 possible types.

So I figure I should change my method's signature to:

> public string Postback([FromBody]string _sfResponse)

But the string is always showing up null (with or without the [FromBody] directive). Seems the ModelBinder insists on participating. Anyway to convince him not to?

Just in case there's anything about routing:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "MyPostback",
    url: "rest/V1/sync/update",
    defaults: new { controller = "Admin", action = "MyPostback" }    
);
```

The controller action:

```
[System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
[System.Web.Mvc.AllowAnonymous]
public string MyPostback([System.Web.Http.FromBody][ModelBinder(typeof(MyResponseModelBinder))] MyResponseToProduct _sfResponse)
{
//stuff
}
```

The json being sent is more complex that average but keep in mind that when the controller's signature is referencing a strongly typed object that matches that json everything works. (and to repeat -- I'm having to accommodate 2 different incoming types which is why I'm needing to take a string at the beginning instead of a model).

```
 {
"results": [
    {
        "errors": {
            "error": "No Error"
        },
        "sku": "70BWUS193045G81",
        "status": "success",
        "productId": "123"
    },
    {
        "errors": {
            "error": "No Error"
        },
        "sku": "70BWUS193045G82",
        "status": "success",
        "productId": "123"
    }
],
"validationType": "products",
"messageId": "ac5ed64f-2957-51b4-8fbb-838e0480e7ad"
}
```

I've added a custom model binder just to be able to peek at values before the controller gets hit:

```
public class MyResponseModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        HttpRequestBase request = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request;
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(request.Form.GetValues("Id"));

        return new MyResponseToProduct()
        {
            results = new List<MyResponseToProduct.Result>()
        };
    }
}
```

When I inspect the values within the custom model binder the controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form is empty (this is a POST submission so the body really should be there, shouldn't it?)

I **can** see my bits data in the *bindingContext.PropertyMetadata* but I can't imagine I'm supposed to be going that deep.

Very strange why Request.Form is empty.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ASP.Net Core:

You can declare your controller action argument as `object` and then call `ToString()` on it, like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Foo([FromBody] object arg)
{
    var str = arg?.ToString();
    ...
}
```

In this example `str` variable will contain JSON string from a request body.

ASP.Net MVC:

Since the previous option does not work in old ASP.Net MVC, as an option you can read data directly from `Request` property in your controller's action. The following extension method will help you with it:

```
public static string GetBody(this HttpRequestBase request)
{
    var requestStream = request?.InputStream;
    requestStream.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(requestStream))
    {
        return reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

And your action will look like that:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("test")]
public ActionResult Foo()
{
    string json = Request.GetBody();
    ...
}
```